# Sort List of C# object by STRING parameter

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

I have a list of `ListUser` class objects. I need to be able to pass in a String value and order by that column in ascending or descending order using text expression. Everything I have seen that uses Lambda expressions, has the object property as a strongly typed value, How can I achieve this by adding in "firstname descending" as a parameter ?

The code is as follows

```
namespace SortLists
{

  class ListUser
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string phonenumber { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var user1 = new ListUser() { id = 1, firstname = "James", lastname = "Smith", company = "Code Logic", phonenumber = "01235 566 456" };
        var user2 = new ListUser() { id = 1, firstname = "Chris", lastname = "Andrews", company = "Adobe", phonenumber = "01235 566 456" };
        var user3 = new ListUser() { id = 1, firstname = "Paul", lastname = "Jones", company = "Microsoft", phonenumber = "01235 566 456" };
        var user4 = new ListUser() { id = 1, firstname = "Peter", lastname = "Williams", company = "Apple", phonenumber = "01235 566 456" };

        List<ListUser> users = new List<ListUser>()
        {
            user1, user2, user3, user4
        };
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use an if else structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add reference to nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

1. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` at the top.
2. Use `var usersSorted = users.AsQueryable().OrderBy("firstname ASC").ToList();`

Comment: For efcore: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with a dictionary. Just start with this:

```
var sortBy = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<ListUser>, IEnumerable<ListUser>>>()
{
    { "firstname", lus => lus.OrderBy(lu => lu.firstname) },
    { "lastname", lus => lus.OrderBy(lu => lu.lastname) },
    { "company", lus => lus.OrderBy(lu => lu.company) },
    { "phonenumber", lus => lus.OrderBy(lu => lu.phonenumber) },
};
```

Then you can easily sort like this:

```
List<ListUser> sorted = sortBy["firstname"](users).ToList();
```

If you want it descending just do this:

```
List<ListUser> sorted = sortBy["firstname"](users).Reverse().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just structure your sort method like so:

```
if(stringPassed == "firstname")
{
  List<ListUser> sortedListUser = listUser.OrderBy(p=>p.firstName).ToList();
}
else if(...) // and so on
```

if you want to order them by desc order just use LINQ's `.OrderByDescending` method.
The other cool approach may be that you set your properties to be objects with

```
string value;
string name;
```

and loop your input string with reflection towards the properties in your class and get the one you want and order it. It's a fancy way to impress your teacher xaxa.